# How to store game level objects in a Swift array?

Tags: arrays, swift, object

I want create an array with information of game level objects for my game. But I'm stuck in creating an appropriate array with this information to run this one later in a loop to place all game objects while loading this level.

This is my array:

```
let level1 =
[
    (
        id: 1,
        position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
        impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
    )
]
let level2 =
[
    (
        id: 1,
        position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
        impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
    ),
    (
        id: 2,
        position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
        impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
    )
]
```

And this is my load level func:

```
func loadLevel(levelNumber: Int = 1) {
    var level = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    switch(levelNumber) {
    case 1:
        level = level1 //Cannot assign a value of type '[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]' to a value of type '[([String: AnyObject])]'
    case 2:
        level = level2 //Cannot assign a value of type '[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]' to a value of type '[([String: AnyObject])]'
    case 3:
        level = level3 //Cannot assign a value of type '[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]' to a value of type '[([String: AnyObject])]'
    default:
        level = level1 //Cannot assign a value of type '[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]' to a value of type '[([String: AnyObject])]'
    }

    for s in level {
        var newShip = Ship(ship: ships[s.id! - 1], position: s.position)
        self.addChild(newShip)
        ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(s.impulse)
    }
}
```

I even do not know if this is a good approach to save/edit level object information.

And when I use:

```
var level = [id:Int, position:CGPoint, impulse:CGVector]() //Use of unresolved identifier 'id'
```

Comment: It's very vague. And what is your question?

Comment: @kostek, I added the error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong type for your `level` variable.  It is not an array of dictionaries.  It is an array of named tuples.  Try declaring `level` like this:

```
var level:[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]
```

---

If instead you put all of your levels in 1 big array, you can access each level with an array index and you won't need a big switch statement.  I recommend telling Swift the type of the array when you declare it:

```
let levels: [[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]] = [
    // level 1
    [
        (
            id: 1,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        )
    ],
    // level 2
    [
        (
            id: 1,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        ),
        (
            id: 2,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        )
    ]
]

func loadLevel(levelNumber: Int = 1) {
    // Subtract 1 since array indices start at 0.  This will crash with Array
    // index out of range if the level doesn't exist.  Take proper precautions.
    let level = levels[levelNumber - 1]

    for s in level {
        var newShip = Ship(ship: ships[s.id - 1], position: s.position)
        self.addChild(newShip)
        ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(s.impulse)
    }
}
```

---

Or you can make `levels` be a dictionary with the level number being the `key`:

```
let levels: [Int:[(id: Int, position: CGPoint, impulse: CGVector)]] = [
    // level 1
    1: [
        (
            id: 1,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        )
    ],
    // level 2
    2: [
        (
            id: 1,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        ),
        (
            id: 2,
            position: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.8),
            impulse: CGVectorMake(-40, 0)
        )
    ]
]

func loadLevel(levelNumber: Int = 1) {
    // Unwrap the level information.  This will crash if it isn't a valid
    // level number.  Take proper precautions.
    let level = levels[levelNumber]!

    for s in level {
        var newShip = Ship(ship: ships[s.id - 1], position: s.position)
        self.addChild(newShip)
        ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(s.impulse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited.  It is an array of named tuples.

Comment: Hehehe yeah - I read first version of answer and thought that might be a good idea to make a function that returns the correct level. Thank you for this great answer!